# JSON request body example swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is there any way to set up example for request body in swagger 2.0?

My scheme is the same like in https://petstore.swagger.io/

My json param:

```
                "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "body",
                    "description": "Pet object that needs to be added to the store",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
                    },
                    "x-example":  "x-example": "{\r\n\"id\":123123123123123123,\r\n\"category\":{\r\n\"id\":44,\r\n\"name\":\"A12312312312312AA\"\r\n},\r\n\"name\":\"X123123123123XX\",\r\n\"photoUrls\":[\r\n\"st123123123ring\"\r\n],\r\n\"tags\":[\r\n{\r\n\"id\":0,\r\n\"name\":\"str123123ing\"\r\n}\r\n],\r\n\"status\":\"avai123123lable\"\r\n}""
                }
            ],
```

I tried everything to setup my own example.

```
x-example: 
 default/(application/json):
```

and so on. No result.

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI 2.x or 3.x? (See [version detection](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md))

Comment: 3.19.5 with json version "swagger": "2.0"